# Looping through same API call using power query in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, web-content

I need to keep running an API call (get request) where I am using web.contents function until the status for the request changes from "null" to "finished", once in finished state I can then retrieve the data.

Any ideas how to construct this loop in Power Query?

Comment: See https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/ for a good tutorial

Comment: Yes thanks for sending. Had already looked at this. I need to loop through one of the objects returned from the api, and if the status isn't what is expected by the condition it keep looping until it is.

Comment: There is a part that says "Since you want to make API calls until reaching the end of the database, you can check whether the List value is empty. Once there are no more records, Power Query will return an empty list."  That is basically what you are doing except for a value instead of for a null